# a linear map $T ∈ L(F^{n} )$ that has exactly m eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So I run into the question:

For each m ∈ {1, ..., n}, give an example of a linear map

$T ∈ L(F^{n} )$

that has exactly m eigenvalues.

And I came up with the matrix A which looks like this:

$$ A= \left(\begin{matrix}\lambda_{1}&0&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&0\\0&\lambda_{2}&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot\\\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot\\\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\lambda_{m-1}&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot\\\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&1&\cdot&\cdot\\\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&1&0\\0&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&0&1\end{matrix}\right) $$

Would it have m eigenvalues? Am I on the right track?

Comment: Providing that the $\lambda_i$ are all distinct, you're not even on the right track... but right on the spot!